# VisualStudio - I can create a control element in time execution?

Tags: visual-studio, directory, visual-studio-2012, checkbox

I have a folder with 100 subfolders.
My app have 20 checkboxes.

When the form loads, the form retreives all the folder names and gives to each checkbox "checkbox.Text" property.

obviusly if I have only 25 checkboxes and 100 folders, i get an "indexOutOfRange" exception.

How to resolve this by adding more checkboxes in time-execution? it's possibly?

PS: I'm begineer with VS

thankyou for read

**UPDATE**: Language is VB.NET the proyect is a windows Form

Comment: Well, each control has a Controls collection to which you can add new controls programmatically. Assuming this is c# and winforms. Can you elaborate on language?

Comment: thankyou, and sorry about that is VB.NET but i can translate online an example wrote in C#... really i don't understand how to use/create/modify a control collection, i'm begineer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, something like

```
dim newCheckBox as new CheckBox()
newCheckBox.Text = "Foo"
targetControl.Controls.Add(newCheckBox)
```

should work. Depending on what the parent control is, and what its layout properties are, you'll want to modify newCheckBox's properties to make them align to screen neatly.

Can use FlowLayoutPanel for example.

Comment: please..how I can add more than one control? for example:         Dim count As Integer = 0
        For Each folder In ThisDir.Subfolders
            Dim newCheckBox(count) As New CheckBox()
            newCheckBox(count).Text = "Foo"
            Panel1.Controls.Add(newCheckBox(count))
        Next

Comment: not sure of your newcheckbox(count) statement. Just remove the parantheses and count. All the created controls will overlap eachother so you wont notice them existing. They all have default 0 x and y and Panel control is not going to automatically layout them as you want.